# Mergen Guest Cart to Customer cart and Customer Cart to Guest Cart via REST API?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api

I am trying to merge/convert a guest cart into a customer cart (vice versa) using the Magento REST API. Right now I am trying to do so by adding the products to the other cart before logging in or out.

Did anyone try to implement this?